# Make a spinner do stuff when its clicks in android?

Tags: android, onclick, spinner

i have a spinner and i want it so that when the actual spinner is clicked (not an item inside it) to execute some code, like a button does. is this possible?? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try and set a listener for [setOnCreateContextMenuListener(OnCreateContextMenuListener listener)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnCreateContextMenuListener%28android.view.View.OnCreateContextMenuListener%29) I'm not sure if that will work. You could also try and set a listener for [setOnTouchListener(OnTouchListener listener)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnTouchListener%28android.view.View.OnTouchListener%29).  Both of those would be set on the spinner object. Try either of those they might get fired when you actually click the spinner.

Ex:

```
    Spinner spinner = this.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    //First Listener
    spinner.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(new OnCreateContextMenuListener(){

        @Override
        public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
            //Your code goes here
        }

    });
    //Second Listener
    spinner.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            //Your code goes here
            return false;
        }

    });
```

Comment: how would i actually use them on my spinner given that my spinner's called 'spinner'?

Comment: nice one lol the second one works for me the first one does nothing but using the second one whatever code i have inbetween the brackets gets executed twice not once?any ideas lol weird problem

Comment: i got it to stop executing twice by adding int x=1;if(x==1){/*do code*/x++}else{}.il post it in 8hours, thanks for your help xP.

Comment: An easy way to solve that is surround all code with if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){}.